# Mandatory cell in Excel prevent second column before first

Tags: excel

In an Excel row I want to prevent data being entered in the second column before the first column has been filled out.

Many Thanks

Comment: I have looked at some VBA solutions which prevent you saving the sheet unless a particular cell has been filled out.  But really I want to stop data being entered in the second column until the first column has been filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom Data Validation to achieve this. Placing on your second column (starting at B2) the Custom Data Validation formula:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A2)<=0
```

This will test to make sure A2 is not blank before allowing any value to be entered in B2. Hope this solves your requirement.

Comment: brilliant, thank you for this.  I didn't think I could do this so simply using data validation i thought i would have been forced to find a VBA solution.

Comment: Well I did have to test but I was inspired by offset conditional formatting formulas. Glad it served your purpose. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Will the below work for you if you changed the range to suit your columns

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Step 1: Check to see if Cell A1 is blank
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("enter sheet name here").Range("A11:C100")) < Sheets("enter sheet name here").Range("A11:C100").Count Then
'Step 2: Blank: cancel the Close and tell the user
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Cells A11 to C100 can not be blank"
'Step 3: Not Blank; Save and Close
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
End Sub
```